# i3 window manager: black screen, no mouse

Tags: archlinux, xorg, i3

I installed i3-gaps on my arch running with a nvidia card. A gnome-session works fine using the nvidia.

After the installation i added to the xinitrc file:

```
exec i3
```

however when I execute `startx` in a tty, the X Server starts successfully, but i3 shows nothing else but black screen (no shortcuts are working)

Answer (score 0):

Since there can be multiple reasons for the observed behavior, I'm suggesting some checkpoints.

1. Please make sure you have installed all the required packages for i3 (or i3-gaps whichever you have installed).
2. Please make sure the exec call (that is "exec i3") is at the bottom / end of the xinitrc file.
3. Also please have a look at the config file located at ~/.config/i3/config.

You can also remove the packages, install them, then run i3-config-wizard to configure the first run behavior of i3wm.